# Why is the SVG image parent element height bigger than the image?

Tags: html, css, svg

I have an inline SVG image wrapped in an absolutely positioned `div`:

```css
.parent {
  position: absolute;
  background-color: black;
}

.parent > svg {
  width: 100%; height: auto;
}
```

```html
<div class="parent">
    <svg width="1440" height="36" viewBox="0 0 1440 36" fill="none" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
        <path d="M1440 0H0V17.778C0 17.778 291.405 57.778 706.982 17.778C1122.56 -22.222 1440 17.778 1440 17.778V0Z" fill="white"></path>
    </svg>
</div>
```

The SVG image height is set to `auto`, so I expected the `.parent` element height to be equal to that of the SVG image. However, it is not. Any ideas why?

Comment: Not the case? What is the case then? Did you take margins and padding into account?

Comment: @Stefan, the snippet is attached. There are not paddings or marings there.

Comment: What happens is the same as to any other inline elements, the same white space character has. Make the `svg` to `display: block` and it goes away

Comment: @LGSon, totally missed that. Thanks!